# Order of insertion of elements that will result in a perfectly balanced Binary Search Tree?

Tags: tree, binary-search-tree

I am trying to work through this question in a textbook and can't seem to fully understand it:

- Determine an order of insertion for these elements that
  will result in a perfectly balanced Binary Search Tree.
- The elements are: {10, 11, 15, 19, 23, 78, 42, 56, 18, 13, 12, 38,
  47}

I am able to construct the BST and balance it correctly, but I'm not sure how to order the elements before constructing the tree to guarantee a balanced tree.

Comment: Hint: what if you filmed the correct insertion order and then ran the film backward?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, we sort these elements, then you start to construct the balanced BST. Now we need to choose one element to be the root of the tree, to guarantee the tree balanced, so we pick the middle element from the sorted elements. Then we need to make a choice which one is the left child. There are two sorted sub arrays left — The one on the left and the one on the right. Here is divide-and-conquer, these two arrays are the sub-problems of the original problem. Then we choose the middle element from the left sorted sub array as the left child node, choose the middle element from the right sorted sub array as the right child node and so on.

So the order of elements before constructing the tree to guarantee a balanced tree is determined as below:

- sort the elements.
- the first element is the middle element from the sorted elements.
- the second element is the middle element from the left sorted array.
- the third element is the middle element from the right sorted array.
- and so on.

for the elements you give, the order is:
19, 12, 42, 10, 15, 23, 56, 11, 13, 18, 38, 47, 78

Comment: I have to work on a very similar assignment, however, our tree needs to be leftist in the end (leafs from left to right, no gaps). Is there an easy way to use your described method for my assignment?